# Preserving Bitmap values when creating a new Bitmap from System.Drawing.Image

Tags: .net, image, gdi+

I'm trying to create a resized image from a bitmap, set a new height/width and a new resolution and save it to PNG. I can do this either from directly A) `Image.FromFile(filename)` or B) `New Bitmap(imageSource)` to create the the ***A*** Bitmap to be passed to ***B***. Both work okay schmokay, but ***A*** does not allow me to set a new width/height on creation (but it does allow me to preserve values with `useIcm=True`) and ***B*** does not allow me to preseve values.

Okay, now on to some code and examples:

1. `Dim sourceBitmap As New
   Bitmap(imagePath & myImage1Name)`
   <-not good at all (#1 overload). Doesn't preserve
   things like `HorizontalResolution`
   or `PixelFormat` on `.Save`
2. `Dim sourceBitmap2 As Bitmap = Image.FromFile(imagePath & myImage1Name,
   True)` <-not good (#5 overload). it *does*
   preserve things like
   `HorizontalResolution` or
   `PixelFormat` on `.Save`, but it
   ***doesn't*** allow me to initialize image at a new size.
3. `Dim targetBitmap As New
   Bitmap(sourceBitmap2, newWidth,
   newHeight)` <-not good. Even though
   `sourceBitmap2` (see #2 above) was
   initialized with `useIcm=True`, it
   doesn't matter once I've passed it
   in as the source in `targetBitmap`.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to contruct a New Bitmap with both something like `useIcm=True` *and* set the width/height at the same time (`Width`/`Height` are read-only properties once it's created).

I've gone down the `Graphics.DrawImage` route as well and it's the same - `Graphics.FromImage(sourceBitmap)` does not preserve values.

Why do I need these values to be preserved? Because I need to convert these pictures to PNG (for file size) with a new resolution and keep the same physical dimensions (w/h in inches) for printing. I know the new pixel width/height needed based on the resolution values I'll pass in with `.SetResolution(xDpi,yDpi)` to preserve physical dimensions, so that's not the problem. The issue is things like the `PixelFormatSize` need to remain unchanged (yes, I've tried `EncoderParameters` - they don't work. I can give you the gory details if you like, but suffice it to say for now, they just don't work).

Whew, got that off my chest! Okay, anyone who really knows how all this works can help?

**EDIT**: Files types needed to pull in to convert to PNG: BMP, TIF, GIF, WMF, EMF.

Comment: Reflector may be your friend here. You may be able to determine an exact combination of constructor and API that gives you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm not familiar with Reflector, but I'll give that a look. Sounds potentially promising.

Answer (score 3):

What about doing something like the following code:  You can Draw the Bitmap on a NEWGraphic.  You can then mess with the size when you redraw it.

```
  Dim NewGraphic As Graphics = Nothing
        Dim OutBMP As Bitmap

        Using bmp As New Bitmap(3264, 4224)
            Try

                NewGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                NewGraphic.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, 3264, 4224)
                NewGraphic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                NewGraphic.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                NewGraphic.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                NewGraphic.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                NewGraphic.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit

                NewGraphic.DrawImage(MetaFileToConvert, 0, 0, 3264, 4224)

                OutBMP = CType(FFConvertToBitonal(CType(bmp, Bitmap)), Bitmap)
                OutBMP.SetResolution(385, 385)

                OutImage = DirectCast(OutBMP, Image)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                NewGraphic.Dispose()

            End Try

        End Using
```

Comment: Thanks pehaada for the response and the code, I appreciate it. Unfortunately, using a `Graphic` object causes even more problems when trying to preserve the settings of the original bitmap. +1 for the code and detailed response though!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do `Dim targetBitmap As New Bitmap(Image.FromFile(imagePath & myImage1Name, True), newWidth, newHeight)`?

Comment: Perfect, don't know how I missed that!